# Tool to force use FILE instead of RAM

Tags: linux, utilities, swap, limit, ram

I'm wondering why there is no such tool like **ram2swap**, similar to cpulimit in parts.

E.g.

There is program daemon.bin.

Let's create temporary swap file ( 1 Gb ):

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.swap bs=1m count=1000
```

Launch:

```
% cpulimit -l 10 ram2swap -f tmp.swap daemon.bin
```

Instead of RAM usage or SWAP, daemon.bin will allocate memory in the `tmp.swap` file.

Dramatically decrease performance, yes. But How this is flexibly.

Comment: not a tool, but you can increase `swapiness` to encourage the kernel to swap to disc more often.

Comment: Yes swappiness (`/proc/sys/vm/swappiness`) is the most direct way to controlling this.

Comment: You can use this command to push blocks back to RAM from swap: `sudo sync; echo 3 >> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: This is offtopic here. I'm not talking about drop_caches and trivial swapiness.

Comment: @AnomalousAwe - not off-topic, I understand what you're asking, there is no such tool, the only way you can influence where something is located (RAM vs. SWAP) is through swappiness or by dropping caches.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such tool because it does not make any sense from a single-program point of view.

One can consider CPU/HDD/RAM/swap as resources. These resources can be shared in different ways by the operating system among processes, users, contexts, etc.

In some specific situations, it makes sense to tell the operating system to enforce hard limits:

- *Don't allow this program to use more than 60% of memory.*
- *Don't allow this user to use more than 20% of the CPU time if another user needs it. Else allow him to use 100% CPU.*
- *Don't allow users from this group to use more than 2 cores.*
- ...

This provide a real *flexibility*: resources are shared between the users according to the administrator whishes and the OS complies.

Why manually putting a program to swap is not a good idea?

- You are basically assuming that you are better than the heuristic in the kernel. The kernel already handles swap space by itself. If a daemon has not been activated for a long time and the OS lacks RAM, it will eventually be put into swap.
- AFAIK, swap is not executable: before being executed, the content of the swap needs to be retrieved into the RAM. So if you were thinking about first class programs being executed from RAM and second class programs being executed from swap: stop now, that won't work.
- "Yes, but that specific daemon is called twice a month. I don't need it in RAM". If it's true, the kernel will put in in swap if you lack RAM.
- "Why waiting for RAM lacking?" Putting things in and out of swap is very expensive, especially on plain old HDD. If your system can keep everything in RAM, it's better to let it do. If you force something into the swap, for the time being, your system will be less responsive. Since your other "1st class" daemons should most probably do some HDD IO too, those will also be slowed down. Same thing when the "2nd class" daemon wakes up and needs to be put into RAM.

Now, why can't a user use a magic command line to put a program in swap?

- It's not clear what should be put into the swap from a userspace (non-kernel) perspective. Your program is linked to `libmylib.so`, should it put that in swap too? And what about `libc.so`?
- What's the intended behaviour actually? Do you want the daemon to be put directly in swap? But it will have to do some initialization work, won't it? Then it will go back to RAM as soon as you'll have it loaded.
- How do you proceed to know the daemon is not used anymore and can be put safely into the swap again?
- Should it be sent back into swap directly or should you wait a little? Otherwise at each sleep, your daemon will be put into swap and at each wake up it will be put back in RAM. If your daemon updates your computer clock for instance, be ready for hours of swapping.
- ...

In short, you need the kernel to handle it and this is precisely what it does. For most of the needs, tweaking the swapiness is more than enough to get a responsive system.

Now, if you really want to
[image: shoot yourself in the foot]
<sub>(source: [freakoutnation.com](http://freakoutnation.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Foot-shot.jpg))</sub>  , the kernel offer this "flexibility" by using `cgroups`. You can obtain what you think you want by setting max mem and max mem+swap for your daemon in `cgroups`. You can obtain a more resonable result by setting per-program swapiness. But either ways, it is not a good idea and I won't go further than [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt) as an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is something kind of what you describe: there is a feature to limit the amount of RAM used by a process (RAM, as opposed to virtual memory). The `RLIMIT_RSS` limit sets an upper bound a program's resident set size, i.e. the part of the memory of that process which is resident in memory (as opposed to swapped out). However, it is not implemented on Linux.

`RLIMIT_RSS` existed in some old Unix systems (BSD only?) but has been dropped from many modern systems. On [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), it existed only on the 2.4 series (and even there didn't fully work). On Solaris it was [dropped](http://www.linuxmisc.com/3-solaris/ceba213b99fdad6c.htm) at some point in the distant past (when <s>Solaris</s> SunOS switched from BSD to System V, maybe?). [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setrlimit) seems to still have it.

I don't know why `RLIMIT_RSS` was removed. [Alan Cox](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/1/9/119) had this to say in 2006:

> The original mm for Linux didn't enforce it as it did not
>   have any way to track RSS that was not computationally expensive. The
>   current mm is probably capable of implementing RSS limits although
>   questions then still remain about what effect this has if a user sets a
>   low RSS limit and then causes a lot of swap thrashing.
>
> If you can see a way to implement it efficiently then go for it.

Since then the topic has come up several times but as far as I know no patch was accepted to the Linux kernel.

One reason that enforcing a limit on physical memory usage for a process is that it's hard to define how much physical memory a process is using. Ok, count its stack and heap (the part that's not swapped out). What about memory-mapped files? To measure the physical memory usage of a process, you have to count the cache used by the files that it maps. What about shared libraries and other shared mappings? If they're used by a single process then obviously they should be counted against it — but when they're used by multiple processes, it's hard to know which process is using which part.

It doesn't make all that much sense to limit physical memory usage of a single process. Given that resource limits are inherited, each child would be allowed to use as much physical memory. It makes a little more sense to allow a limit on physical memory for a set of processes. Linux has this feature built into [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), a partial virtualization system where a process and its descendants run in a container which can have its own filesystem root, its own network controllers, its own resource limits, etc. A [cgroup's memory usage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt) can be limited with the `memory.limit_in_bytes` parameter (`memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes` controls the use of RAM plus swap). The documentation warns that pages shared between groups are assigned in a somewhat arbitrary way (“Shared pages are accounted on the basis of the first touch approach. The
cgroup that first touches a page is accounted for the page.”). There [may be other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043709/resident-set-size-rss-limit-has-no-effect/6365534#6365534) in which the limit isn't strictly enforced.

The other part of what you're asking for is to have a dedicated swap file for a process. This would require considerable complexity in the kernel. Remember that pages can be shared; which swap file do you use if the two processes have different swap space assigned to them? On the other hand, the feature can be implemented fairly easily from the process side: map a file to memory. For shared pages, there's still a single file. As a side benefit, different areas of a process can use different “swap space”.